# OrCad PSpice: Did I design the circuit wrong?

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, pspice, orcad, inverting-amplifier

I keep getting 0 volts when I design this circuit but I was supposed to get a value of 1V at least.

How I would be able to fix this circuit?

[image]

The circuit that we were supposed to design was Fig(74).

[image]

Every time I do a new simulation and plot the output and input, the voltage output is just a flat line at 0V.

What could I possibly be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

> *What could I have been possibly doing wrong?*

It appears that you have Vdd and Vss swapped around on your op-amp supply pins: -

[image]

Comment: @MarieCorCruz - if you have finished with this question and answer, please consider formally accepting my answer so that it can be closed down. In doing so, it allows future readers of this question to see that the answer was correct. If there are problems with my answer or things you do not understand, please leave a comment.

Comment: @MarieCorCruz hello, earth to Marie.....

Comment: @MarieCorCruz Hi Marie - have you got any comments on this answer or is it clear to you?